# Clarification on the theorem 2.33 of Baby Rudin: If $K \subset Y \subset X$, then $K$ is compact relative to $Y$ iff $K$ is compact relative to $X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

The theorem is that: *Suppose $K \subset Y \subset X$. Then $K$ is compact relative to $X$ if and only if $K$ is compact relative to $Y$*. Rudin begins the proof by stating that:

> Suppose $K$ is a compact relative to $X$, and let $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ be a collection of sets, open relative to $Y$, such that $K \subset \cup_{\alpha}V_{\alpha}$.

The opening statement makes me feel uneasy, as we are directly taking an open cover for $K$, whose sets $V_{\alpha}$ are also open relative to $Y$. Namely, when we assume that $K$ is open relative to $X$, then by definition for any open cover for $K$ in $X$ there exists a finite subcover. But why are the sets of the open cover (note: not the subcover) necessarily open in $Y$? I say *necessarily*, as I have understood the process for showing the theorem to be true that i.) assume that $K$ is compact in $X$, take an arbitrary open cover for $K$ in $X$ so it has a finite subcover. Then show that any open cover for $K$ in $Y$ also has a finite subcover, so that $K$ is compact in $Y$. I don't quite understand why there should be a linkage between the openness of the cover of $K$ in $X$ and openness of the (same) cover relative to $Y$.

Comment: The answer by quasi is IMO of more clarity: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3879653/1195730 "It doesn't assert the existence of a relatively open cover of $K$. What it asserts is that "If a collection of sets is a relatively open cover of $K$, then there is a finite subcollection that also covers $K$"."

Comment: Personally I find it much more comfortable if proof in both directions is started by assuming the existence of the respective open cover, e.g. Suppose $K$ is  compact relative to $X$, we then assume that there exists an open cover $\bigcup{V_\alpha} \subset X$, since $K \subset \bigcup{V_\alpha}$ and $K \subset Y$, $K \subset\bigcup{V_\alpha} \cap Y$, at the same time $G_\alpha$’s being open rel. to $X$ guarantees the openness of $V_\alpha$ rel. to $Y$ (proof is simple). If such open cover doesn’t exist the proof is trivial.

Comment: The opposite direction then requires some application of theorem 2.30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument is a bit different than the one you've outlined at the end of your question. It goes like this:

Suppose $K$ is compact relative to $X$. We will show that $K$ is compact relative to $Y$. It is enough to show that for any open (relative to $Y$) cover of $K$, there is a finite subcover. Let $\{V_\alpha\}$ be a collection of sets, open relative to Y, such that $K \subset \cup_{\alpha}V_{\alpha}$. We will show that $\{V_\alpha\}$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: Would the "if" direction be satisfied if there is no open (relative to $Y$) cover of $K$? That is there is at least one open cover of $K$ in $X$, but no cover which is open relative to $Y$.

Comment: That can't happen, since $Y$ is always open relative to itself.